# Python - How do I create a sliding window of columns in a text file?

Tags: python, text, sliding-window

I have text files from sensor data such as accelerometers and gyroscopes such as:

```
% Accelerometer data recorded with 'snsrlog'
% 
% Sampling frequency: 100 Hz
% 
% Label description:
%    0: Default Label
%    1: pick up phone
% 
% Column description:
%    1: Seconds.milliseconds since 1970
%    2: Number of skipped measurements
%    3: Acceleration value in x-direction
%    4: Acceleration value in y-direction
%    5: Acceleration value in z-direction
%    6: Label used for the current sample
% 
% 
1495573445.162   0   0.021973    0.012283    -0.995468   1
1495573445.172   0   0.021072    0.013779    -0.994308   1
1495573445.182   0   0.020157    0.015717    -0.995575   1
1495573445.192   0   0.017883    0.012756    -0.993927   1
1495573445.202   0   0.021194    0.012161    -0.994705   1
1495573445.212   0   0.019638    0.013718    -0.994019   1
1495573445.222   0   0.019440    0.010803    -0.994476   1
```

with much more in the files.

I want to create a sliding window of size 50 for each column of accelerometer axes because the sampling frequency is 100Hz. I can print out each line of the first column like this:

```
def sliding_window(filename, stepSize, windowSize):
    with open(filename) as infile:
        for line in infile:
            print(line.split()[0])
```

However, I shouldn't be printing out the first 17 lines as they are just comments in the text file. How would I go about making this sliding window?

Comment: Oops. I shouldn't have done that. I'll edit that out.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `startswith` condition:

```
if not line.startswith('%'):
    print(line.split()[0])
```

Comment: Thanks that helps with the comments. I'm still not sure how to only go through, say the first x elements in each column.

Comment: @dirtysocks45 `line.split()[:x]`

Comment: Sorry I meant first x elements in a specific column. Not every element in the first x columns.

Comment: @dirtysocks45 oh, then just change `0` with the column number, set a counter `c = 0` before the loop, and add to the condition `and c < x`, while ending each round with `c += 1`